# Why Vite build throw the Error [commonjs--resolver] Failed to resolve entry for package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vite

I have some package on the node modules that have a *package.json*

```
{
  "sideEffects": false,
  "module": "./index.js",
  "main": "../node/{moduleName}/index.js",
  "types": "./index.d.ts"
}
```

When vite trying to build it throw the error

[commonjs--resolver] Failed to resolve entry for package "/drone/src/node_modules/{module}/core/node_modules/@mui/material/LinearProgress". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/drone/src/node_modules/{module}/core/node_modules/@mui/material/LinearProgress/index.js'
error during build:

My vite config is

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import RubyPlugin from 'vite-plugin-ruby';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    assetsInlineLimit: 2048,
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output:{
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDom'
        },
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
            return id.toString().split('node_modules/')[1].split('/')[0].toString();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [RubyPlugin()],
});
```

I find this [Solution](https://github.com/indentjs/objectorarray/issues/3), but I can't remove it from the package.json

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Not sure if this is an option for you, but you can resolve this by removing  `manualChunks`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the vite bundler, you can resolve it with an alias using https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias
Ex:

```
resolve: {
  alias: [
    {
      find: /@mui\/material/,
      replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', '@mui', 'material'),
    },
  ],
},
```

Comment: I faced a similar problem with a dependency that used `function-bind`. The package.json of `function-bind` points to `index` whereas it should be `index.js`. By adding the alias I was able to fix the problem. Thanks for the tip @DarkAngel!